# How to populate data repeatedly from list returned by action in mvc4?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am a kind of newbie and I am having problem in reading data that I want to get from database and want to show in a span. My problem is this that I have brought data in controller but now I want to show that data in view. I am able to access specific data from list but I want to show data in repeat mode as like news. 
My controller part is given here

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Quote> quote = dbContext.quotes.ToList();                
            return View(quote);                
        }
```

View part is

```
<blockquote> 
       @foreach 
        (var items in @Model) 
        { 
             @items.quote 
        } 
</blockquote>
```

what logic should I implement here to fetch data in repeat mode so that I can every quote on hourly basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [aniruddhanath](http://www.jqueryscript.net/plus/search.php?keyword=aniruddhanath) whose jquery plugin helped me for this scenerio.

> Index.cshtml

```
<div id="crotator">
        <div id="quotes">
            @foreach (var news in Model)
            {    
                <p>@news.News</p>
            }
        </div>    
        <div id="authors">
            @foreach (var news in Model)
            {

                <p>- @news.Author</p>
            }    
        </div>    
    </div>
```

> Script Block

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Content-Rotator-Plugin-Crotator/js/jquery-crotator.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#quotes").crotator({
        // optional changes
        timeofExistence: 5000,
        typeofTag: "<h3/>",
        tagClass: "quotes"
    });
    $("#authors").crotator({
        // optional changes
        timeofExistence: 5000,
        typeofTag: "<h4/>",
        tagClass: "authors"
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `location.reload();` in javascript which will re-load your page every hour and fetch the latest news:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCTutorial.Models.Quote>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Quotes</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(function ()
        {
            location.reload();

        }, 3600000);//3600000 milliseconds = 1 hour
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <blockquote>
        @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            <span>@String.Format("{0}-{1}",item.ID,item.QuoteName)</span><br />
        }
    </blockquote>
</body>
</html>
```

### EDIT

To get only the latest items periodically you could make an AJAX call using `$.getJSON` and append the latest items to the list.

**Controller action method:**

```
public JsonResult GetLatestNews()
{
    //Write the query here to get the latest items...
    List<Quote> quotes = dbContext.quotes.ToList();
    return Json(quotes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCTutorial.Models.Quote>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Quotes</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetLatestNews","Quote")", function (data) {

                    for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++){
                        var id = data[i].ID;
                        var quoteName = data[i].QuoteName;

                        var quote = "<span>" + id + "-" + quoteName + "</span><br />";
                        $("#quotes").append(quote);
                    }
                });

            }, 3600000);//3600000 milliseconds = 1 hour
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <blockquote id="quotes">
        @foreach (var item in @Model)
        {
            <span>@String.Format("{0}-{1}", item.ID, item.QuoteName)</span><br />
        }
    </blockquote>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But don't you think that I am to make changes in action so that it should return specific value rather than returning the entire list. How to make it happen?

Comment: Why you still have foreach loop when there is no data returning from action()?

Comment: When the page initially loads it executes a controller action to get the current news items and then every hour an AJAX call will me made to get the latest items using $.getJSON and append them to the original items.If you don't want that you can always leave it out.

Comment: One last question this is keep adding quote rather than showing only one information at a time. Any suggestion?

Comment: Empty out the <blockquote id="quotes"> element in jQuery if you want to clear it.You need to learn how to do research and do some trial and error.Put effort into figuring problems out on your own

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118896/discussion-between-ravikant-hudda-and-denis-wessels).